# Select default value for DropDownListFor using ViewBag as SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have a list of Agents stored in ViewBag

```
ViewBag.Agents = new SelectList(db.Users.ToList(), "Id", "UserName", string.Empty);
```

In my View I have display this as a `DropDownListFor`

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => a.AgentList, ViewBag.Agents as SelectList, new { @class = "form -control", @style = "width:130px; height:30px" })
```

However, my  list is not showing the already selected Agent as Default. What am I missing? How can I set the Dropdownlist to display selected Agent as default?

I even tried this but nothing work:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => a.AgentList, new SelectList( ViewBag.Agents as SelectList, a.AgentName), new { @class = "form -control", @style = "width:130px; height:30px" })
```

Here is my model

```
[Display(Name = "Agent ID")]
public string AgentID { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Agent Name")]
public string AgentName { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Agent")]
public List<ApplicationUser> AgentList { get; set; }
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. It binds to a single value so the proprty your binding to needs to be `int` (assuming the `Id` peoperty of `User` is `int`

Comment: any code suggestion?

Comment: Cannot possibly help without more information. What is `ViewBag.Agents`? (show your controller code) and what property do you want to bind to?

Comment: `ViewBag.Agents` is my list of Users (EF identity user). I have a ticketing system and its model contains the Agents ID and Name. I want to bind the Selected's EF identity user to this Agent property where I want the EF username to be the Agent Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below step for bind the selected value in **DropDownListFor**.

Step:- 1 `ViewBag.Agents= db.Users.ToList();`

Step:- 2 `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.AgentID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Agents, "Id", "UserName",2))`

Comment: not working. still showing the first item in the list as a default for dropdownlist.

Comment: there is no error. It just still display the first item of the list as default value.

Comment: any thought or suggestion?

Comment: actually this comes really close:
actually it should be
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.AgentID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Agents, "Id", "UserName", a.AgentID))` something like that

Answer (score 1):

What I have found, is that if the form is bound to a Model, the model value (which is probably null by default) will override whatever selected value is set by the ViewBag List. So, it is best to set the default value inside the model.

For example:

[ViewModel for the form] ModelFormType ViewModel = new ModelFormType();
ModelFormType.UserId = 11 (default user Id).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => a.AgentList, new SelectList( ViewBag.Agents, Model.AgentName), new { @class = "form -control", @style = "width:130px; height:30px" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you make use of this overload of selectlist

[SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    object selectedValue
)
```

It will initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text field, and a selected value.

**So you code will change like:**

```
ViewBag.Agents = new SelectList(db.Users.ToList(), "Id", "UserName", 10 /*Default user Id*/);
```