# How to set default value for DropDownList in View using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, select, razor, model-view-controller, dropdown

I'm  trying create a DropDownList in my View with data of a SelectList passed to my View using ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.OtherKeysList = new SelectList(list, "OtherKey");
```

In my View i create a WebGrid with a column representing this DropDownList like this:

```
 grid.Column(columnName: "OtherKey", header: "OtherKey", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownList("OtherKey", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OtherKeysList, new { @class = "extra-class" })</text>)))
```

However this list just uses the first item in the list as its default value. How to set another value of this list to its default value?

UPDATE:

When i try the following code:

```
public ActionResult EditMapping(int id)
    {
        var list = new ListWithDuplicates();

        var v = (from a in dbProducts.MapperConfigs
                 where
                    a.MappingID.Equals(id)
                 select a
                   );

        foreach (var item in v)
        {
            list.Add(item.OtherKey, item.OtherKeyType);
        }

        ViewBag.TotalRows = v.Count();

        ViewBag.OtherKeysList = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Key, Value = x.Key, Selected = x.Key == "keyC" ? true : false });

        ViewBag.MappingName = (from a in dbProducts.MappingNames
                               where
                                  a.MappingID.Equals(id)
                               select a.Name
                   ).First();

        var data = v.ToList();
        return View(data);
    }
```

I'm getting the following result:

[image]

However this is configured:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

Key1  :  DropDownlist with default value keyA

Key2  :  Dropdownlist with default value keyB

Key3  :  DropDownlist with default value keyC

Key4  :  Dropdownlist with default value keyD

Comment: You want to select a value from your model or a fixed value?

Comment: From my model, but not the first. I want to choose one myself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068487/select-default-value-for-dropdownlistfor-using-viewbag-as-selectlist

Comment: @NielsStenden Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can achieve your desired result by manipulating the default **SelectListItem** in the `list` which is binded to **SelectList**.

```
var defaultItem = new SelectListItem()
{
   Value = 1,
   Text = "Default Item",
   Selected = true
};
```